# Smartsheet API Doesn't Return All User's Sheets

Tags: smartsheet-api

I'm using the GET /sheets call to list all of a user's Smartsheets but am having an issue. The response object contains most of the user's sheets, but doesn't contain any sheets where the user's accessLevel is OWNER.

Here is the call I'm making:

```
GET https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/
```

With a header

```
Key: Authorization
Value: Bearer <access token here>
```

Is there a setting or API parameter I'm missing?

I looked through the Smartsheet API docs and FAQ for answers but couldn't find anything related so apologies if this is already answered somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the [API docs](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?shell#list-sheets), the **List Sheets** operation should return all of the sheets that the user (access token owner) has access to -- including any sheets that the user owns (`accessLevel = OWNER`) or has otherwise been [granted access to](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?shell#access-levels). I've never seen it *not* work this way. A couple of thoughts / troubleshooting suggestions:

- Is it possible that the user to whom the `Bearer` token belongs does not actually own any sheets (i.e., that they have access to sheets because they've been "shared" to sheets, but aren't actually the owner of the sheets)?
- If you have access to an API access token that belongs to user who has Admin rights in Smartsheet (within the same Org as the User for whom you're trying to identify "owned" sheets), you could execute a [List Org Sheets](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?shell#list-org-sheets) request and examine its response (which will contain all sheets owned by members of the organization to which the Admin belongs) for any sheet objects where **owner** or **ownerId** corresponds to the user for whom you're trying to identify "owned" sheets. The number of sheets "owned by" userX in the **Get Org Sheets** response (using the Admin token) should match the number of sheets where `accessLevel = OWNER` in the **Get Sheets** response (using UserX's token).

**Update** (re paging):

Also note that the **Get Sheets** operation is one of several Smartsheet API operations that [support paging of results](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?shell#paging). If you're not seeing the sheets you expect to see in the API response, it's possible that results are being paged and it just so happens that the objects you're looking for are not contained within the initial page of results (default page size = 100). To see if this is the case, you could try including the `includeAll=true` querystring parameter on the API request URL (which tells Smartsheet to not page the results -- i.e., all results should be included within the response).

Comment: It was the pagination. After I added the includeAll=true query parameter, the missing sheets showed up!

Comment: Glad that you figured it out. One additional note -- the reason that results are paged by default is to ensure that the API response body is never large enough to negatively affect performance. While using the `include=all` querystring parameter on the **Get Sheets** operation will work okay to a point, if you ever reach a point of the response returning thousands of sheets, I'd suspect that using `include=all` would no longer be feasible. In that case, you'd need to use the paging-related attribute values in the initial API response to get the paged results by using multiple API requests.